# Getting error :videoio(MSMF): async ReadSample() call is failed with error status: -2147023169" spammed at me together with a "can't read frame" error

Tags: python, timer, windows-10, opencv

This is my code:

```
import cv2 .  
from threading import Timer

name = 1
time = 1

def pic():
    time = +1
    cam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    retval, frame = cam.read()
    if retval != True:
    raise ValueError("Can't read frame")

    cv2.imwrite('img' + name + '.png', frame)
    name = name + 1

while time != 4:
t = Timer(time, pic)
t.start()
```

This code is supposed to take 4 pictures one second apart, but all i get is the error mentioned above, and "raised unknown C++ exception!"
when i try to run it it slows my entire PC and it just keeps giving more and more errors. 
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I was able to fix the issues with your code (there were several of them):

```
import cv2
from threading import Timer

def pic():
    global name
    cam = cv2.VideoCapture(0+cv2.CAP_DSHOW)
    retval, frame = cam.read()
    if retval != True:
        print("Can't read frame")
    cv2.imwrite('img' + str(name) + '.png', frame)
    name = name + 1

if __name__ == '__main__':
    name = 1
    time = 0

    while time != 4:
        t = Timer(1, pic)
        t.start()
        t.join()
        time=time+1
```

Issues:

1. > error :videoio(MSMF): async ReadSample() call is failed with error status: -2147023169“ spammed at me together with a ”can't read frame"

   This happens because your PC by default takes up the MSMF (microsoft media foundation) API for capturing your default camera. There might be some error in the API so you can always capture using another API by explicitly specifying it as I have done. For more info GOTO: https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d0/da7/videoio_overview.html
2. It is advised that you use the `if __name__ == '__main__':` whenever you are using multiprocessing or threading classes
3. If you are not passing a variable defined in the `main()` section then you need to define it as `global` in the called function.
4. You cannot call the same thread again and again without closing it
   `t.join()` does just that
5. `cv2.imwrite()` does not take numerical value so you need to convert your integer `(name)` to string